# Can't parse JSON object properly

Tags: javascript

I try to parse this JSON object, but always got `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

JSON

```
{
    "success": {
        "name": "MY NAME"
    }
}
```

JS

```
fetch("http://MYAPP/api/details")
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
                }
                return response.text(); 
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data.success.name); // <= ERROR
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error.message);
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) about the fetch api and `response.json()`

```
fetch("http://MYAPP/api/details")
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json(); // <---- this is what you want
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.success.name); // <= ERROR
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error.message);
        });
```

If you did just want to get the text and then parse it, do it like you did but then do `const dataObj = JSON.parse(data); console.log(dataObj.success.name);`

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript function `JSON.parse()` to convert text into a JavaScript object:

```
fetch("http://MYAPP/api/details")
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
        }
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(data).success.name); // <= ERROR
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message);
    });
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse JSON to object first.

```
let parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(parsedData);
```

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)